# How to bind dynamic views in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-view, butterknife

I'm using butterknife in a fragment.  I have 2 two ViewPagers which are in the `header.xml`. 
And I don't want to use `findViewById()` to instantiate them. 
I tried to use `ButterKnife.bind(this,header)`, but it doesn't allow me to bind twice. Is there a way to solve this case?

(sorry for my poor expression,English is not my native language)

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, inflate);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        mPagerMenu = (ViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.pager_menu);
        mPagerAd = (ViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.pager_ad);

        return inflate;
    }
```

Comment: Try this `ButterKnife.bind(getActivity());`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, null);

        View header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.header, null);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, header);
        mPagerMenu = (ViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.pager_menu);
        mPagerAd = (ViewPager) header.findViewById(R.id.pager_ad);

        return inflate;
    }
```

**NOTE:- You can only bind one Layout at a time ......**

Comment: thanks, but i also have views in my fragment_a.xml.  if bind the header,then i still have to use findViewById to instantiate views in fragment_a.xml

Comment: Butterknife bind the all view with layout and if it not find any View then it give you some error .....

Comment: and if you wanted to bind 2 different view then you have to go with `findViewById()` . It is not possible with the Butterknife ...........

Answer (score 1):

> And I don't want to use findViewById()

Initialize your view id by **@BindView(R.id.yourViewId)** after these annotation no more need **findViewById**.

```
  @BindView(R.id.pager_menu) ViewPager pagerMenu;
  @BindView(R.id.pager_ad) ViewPager pagerAd;

  @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    // TODO Use fields...
    return view;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forget about Butterknife and use mvvm (databinding): https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html. In long shot it is a best solution. 
With it, just create two view models, two views and two bindings

Answer (score 0):

In a onCreateView you can only bind one view because you have to retuen one view.

```
ButterKnife.bind(this, inflate);
return inflate;
```

Then you can use inflate to declare another view like....

```
mPagerMenu = (ViewPager) inflate.findViewById(R.id.pager_menu);
mPagerAd = (ViewPager) inflate.findViewById(R.id.pager_ad);
```

Comment: I can not put the 2 pagers in the my main fragment_a.xml,  cuz they are the headerViews of a ListView.  Thanks anyway,now i understand it is not possible to inflate two different views at the same time